# How to wait until service constructor called and execution completed in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have stored api_url in indexed db using NgxIndexedDBService. Now I have to fetch api_url before any call is made in the service. But when I try to call the any service method from constructor of component, it throws an exception as api_url is undefined because subscribe method is still fetching the data from IndexedDB

```
this.dbService.getByKey('CompanyInfo', 'test').subscribe((key: any) =>
{
    this.apiendpoint = key.API_URL;
});
```

please suggest any approach to wait until the service constructor execution get completed before any service call? or please suggest any other approach?

Comment: How about calling service inside subscribe success?

this.dbService.getByKey('CompanyInfo', 'test').subscribe((key: any) =>
{
    this.apiendpoint = key.API_URL;
    // call service after this point.
});

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap with a function that wait until the apiendpoint will be valid

// create subject that emits when the data was ready

```
@Output() public apiendpointChanged: Subject<any> = new Subject();


this.dbService.getByKey('CompanyInfo', 'test').subscribe((key: any) =>
{
    this.apiendpoint = key.API_URL;
    this.apiendpointChanged.next(this.apiendpoint);
});
```

// create a function that check if the data already filled - return the data otherwise wait until the data filled.

```
  public getData(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        if (this.apiendpoint) {
          resolve( this.apiendpoint)
        }
        else {
          const subs = this.apiendpointChanged.subscribe(data => {
          resolve( this.apiendpoint)
            subs.unsubscribe();
          })
        }
      } catch (error) {
        reject(error)
      }
    })
  }
```

when you need the apiendpoint  value just add this call:
await getData();